# How to prevent outputpanel from rerendering when javascript is fired

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, rerender

I have a lookup field that inserts a row of fields onto my page. I have an outputpanel that surrounds the html which needs to be rerendered. The problem is, inside that outputpanel I have a few selectLists (Current Client) that unhide a div (#questionaire) based on an option. How do I prevent that outputpanel from refreshing/rerendering when the javascript fires? I also have javascript firing off inside the #questionaire div.

**Flow**
I select "Yes" or "No" for "Current Client" and javascript unhides the #questionaire div. If the answer is "No", the "Who do they currently bank with?" question unhides.

**jQuery**

```
$('.select_questionaire').change(function(){
    var option_container = $(this).attr('data-options');
    if($(this).val() != ""){
        $(this).getParent(3).find('div[data-options="'+option_container+'"]').removeClass('hidden');
        if($(this).val() == "No"){
            $(this).getParent(3).find('div[data-options="'+option_container+'"]').find('li.bank').removeClass('hidden');
        }
    }
})

jQuery.fn.getParent = function(num) {
    var last = this[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        last = last.parentNode;
    }
    return jQuery(last);
};
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="cpa-list">
    <apex:outputPanel id="cpa_outerpanel">
    <li class="exclude_hidden">
        <apex:inputField html-placeholder="Search by Client Name" value="{!contactLookup.Contact__c}" required="false" /> 
        <label>Search Existing Clients/Prospects</label>
        <apex:actionSupport action="{!addContactToList}" event="onchange" focus="CPA_repeat" rerender="cpa_outerpanel" id="addContact_cpa" oncomplete="unhide_row('cpa-list');" />
    </li>
    <apex:repeat id="CPA_repeat" var="index" value="{!contactCPA}">
    <li class="hidden">
        <ul class="no-margin">
            <li class="exclude_hidden no-padding">
                <apex:inputText styleClass="otherText" value="{!contactCPA[index].Name}" />
                <label>Name</label>
            </li>
            .....
            <li class="exclude_hidden">
                <apex:selectList value="{!contactCPA[index].Is_Client__c}" size="1" styleClass="select_questionaire" html-data-options="cpa_questionaire" >
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Client_Options}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
                <label>Current Client?</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- start questionnaire -->
        <div id="questionnaire" class="select_extend_container hidden" data-options="cpa_questionaire">
            <div class="questions">
                <ul>
                    <li class="exclude_hidden" data-options="cpa_professional">
                        <strong>Have you met with the professional?</strong>
                        <select name="select" class="selectOptions">
                            <option value="">choose one</option>
                            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            <option value="No">No</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <li class="hidden" data-options="cpa_professional">
                        <strong>If no, why? </strong>
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="please provide a reason here" class="error" />
                    </li>
                    <li class="hidden bank">
                        <strong>Who do they currently bank with?</strong>
                        <apex:selectList value="{!crCPA[index].Client_Prospect__r.Banks_With__c}" size="1" >
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!BanksWith_Options}"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end questionnaire -->
        <div style="margin: 0px auto; text-align:center; padding:10px"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default openall fl_addOther">Add Additional CPAs</a> </div>
    </li>
    </apex:repeat>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you provide the flow which you are going through? You select the Current client selectlist than how are you displaying the questionnaire div? js or rerender?

Comment: I would either use jQuery, or use the native Visualforce rerendering functionality...not mix the two at the same time. I think the two will always be fighting for control.

Comment: @Peter that works. Going to opt with visualforce.

Answer (score 0):

Opted to use Visualforce rerendering...

```
<div id="questionnaire" class="hidden" style="display:{!if(showQuestionaireDiv,"block","none")};">
...
</div>
```